# Unresolved Promise issue in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm getting an unresolved Promise.

I have this function:

```
export async function readData(dir) {
await fs.readFile(dir, `utf-8`, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("data1:", data)
    return data
})
}
```

Which I'm calling from this function:

```
app.get('/server/survey', (ctx) => {
let dir = path.join(__dirname, 'src/DB/index.json')
let data = funcs.readData(dir)
data.then((result) => {
    console.log("Content:", result)
    ctx.body = `${result}` 
})
```

The first one logs out the data correctly but the second logs out an unresolved Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` doesn't return a promise, so you can't `await` on it.

You have to wrap it with a promise manually:

```
export function readData(dir) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(dir, `utf-8`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      console.log("data1:", data);
      return resolve(data);
    })
  });
}
```

Or promisify `fs.readFile`, for instance using Node v8's [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const util     = require('util');
const fs       = require('fs');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function readData(dir) {
  let data = await readFile(dir, `utf-8`);
  console.log("data1:", data)
  return data;
}
```

Instead of using Node v8, you can also use a library like [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) that provides promisification.

Notice in the `await` example that the callback is not being used anymore.

Comment: That worked thanks.  Should have tried that.  Just went with the manual promise approach above.  thx!

Comment: @Fedreg I forgot to mention [`pify`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pify), which is a nice small lib to promisify callback-based functions :)

Comment: I'll take a look at it.  Thanks again!